# Integration issue with CCAvenue MCPG

Tags: php, ajax, opencart, ccavenue

I am using opencart version 1.5.5.1 with toy theme (check [here](http://www.eklavya.in/pitara/index.php?route=checkout/checkout)) I Installed module [AJAX Quick Checkout](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=15580) it works fine other payment options bu only for CCAvenue MCPG it shows following notice.

```
Notice: Undefined index: comment in /home/eklavya/public_html/pitara/catalog/controller/payment/ccavenuepay.php on line 0
Notice: Undefined index: comment in /home/eklavya/public_html/pitara/catalog/controller/payment/ccavenuepay.php on line 0
```

The payment processing done as it should be but this warning displayed on screen when I click ccAvenue Pay Now option.

I did not get the line 0.

Comment: can you post the code where the error occurs

Comment: The notice is on controller/payment/ccavenuepay.php on line 0 an the file is in encoded format by CCAvenue.

Comment: PHP displays ' on line 0 ' if there is an eval'd statement ( what is probably the case, since you say that the file is in ' encoded format ').

Comment: What I suppose to do then?